# How to add Glassfish 4.1 Server runtime to Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have been using Eclipse Indigo and would like to deploy my projects to the new Glassfish 4.1 server downloaded recently.

The Glassfish Tool for Indigo plugin does not allow me to add a Glassfish 4.0 (and plus) server runtime and it only allows a Glassfish Server up to 3.1.

Is there a way to add Glassfish Server 4.1 to Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this link:https://glassfish.java.net/ide.html

This should answer your question.

Comment: Does it mean it can by no means run with Indigo ?

Comment: Yes, the eclipse indigo does not support.Change to the eclipse higher version to use glassfish4.1